# How can I get HTML5 video playback accelerated using VDPAU?

Tags: linux, video, gpu, html5

For systems that have accelerated video playback using VDPAU, how can I use this capability to accelerate playback of HTML5 videos?  I know, for instance, with Firefox you can enable GPU-based compositing, but this still uses software decoding, which can be problematic on machines with low CPU capacity.  Hardware decoding, however, is available in many machines.  It works in VLC, for example.  But what about for HTML5 videos?